# Why am i getting an out of bounds error?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

```
public static void randomNumberGame() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random r = new Random();
    int x; 
    int y; 
    int random;
    int total = 0;
    int[][] board = new int[5][5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.print(" " + (i + 1) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");

    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(i + 1);
        for (int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++) {
            board[i][j] = 0;
            System.out.print("[ ]");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++) {
            random = r.nextInt(10) + 1;
            if (board[i][j] == 0) {
                board[i][j] = random;
            }

        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please choose x coordinate for spot " + (i + 1));
        x = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please choose y coordinate for spot " + (i + 1));
        y = input.nextInt(); 

        total += board[x][y];
            System.out.println(total);            

    }


}
```

The output is as follows:

> 1  2  3  4  5
>
> 1[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
>
> 2[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
>
> 3[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
>
> 4[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
>
> 5[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
>
> Please choose x coordinate for spot 1:
>       5
>
> Please choose y coordinate for spot 1:
>       5

Exception Stack Trace -

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
>    
>        at chapter.pkg9.and.pkg10.test.Chapter9And10Test.randomNumberGame(Chapter9And10Test.java:117)
>    
>        at chapter.pkg9.and.pkg10.test.Chapter9And10Test.main(Chapter9And10Test.java:22)
>       C:\Users\Lance\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
>   
>     BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

Line 117 is the one containing this `total += board[x][y];`

Comment: because an array of length `5` has indices `0` to `4`.

Answer (score 2):

Because 5 (the value you've entered for both `x` and `y`) is not a valid `x` or `y` value. The valid indexes for your arrays are 0 to 4, inclusive. (As in all of your loops setting things up.) Either have your user enter a value from 0-4 (inclusive), or allow them to enter 1-5 (inclusive) and remove one from `x` and `y` prior to using them.

Comment: So i would have to do:

    System.out.println("Please choose x coordinate for spot " + (i + 1));
            x = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please choose y coordinate for spot " + (i + 1));
            y = input.nextInt();

Comment: Something like `total += board[x-1][y-1];` would be fine.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to fix formatting, I don't know how to format code in the comments

Comment: @Lance EIther make your user enter 0-4, or make them enter 1-5 and subtract 1 from `x` and `y` prior to using them.

Comment: @ T.J. I understand now thanks

Comment: You forgot to check if values of `x` and `y` are inbound of your 2d array. Remember: `int[][] board = new int[5][5]` bound is `bound[0-4][0-4]`!!